# why my imageview doesn't take the bitmap and show it?

Tags: java, android

```
public class UserlistActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static ListView userlist;
    static String[] users;
    ImageView user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_userlist);
        setIDs();
        Bitmap userphoto = null;
        try {
            userphoto = getBitmapFromAsset("user dashboard.png");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new Gate(this, "USERLIST").execute();
        String mDrawableName = "user dashboard";
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "assets", getPackageName());
        user.setImageResource(resID);
        user.setImageBitmap(userphoto);
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName) throws IOException
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        return bitmap;
    }

    private void setIDs() {
        userlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userlist);
        View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.userlist_list_item, null);
        user = (ImageView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.user);
    }

    static void fillData(Context context) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.userlist_list_item, R.id.listtext, users);
        userlist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

here I am trying to getbitmap ( which is working in other activities fine ) and attatch it to image view that is part of a list item custom layout that I pass to adapter , but I don't know where is the issue , the image doesn't appear

**EDIT ::**

I fixed it by adding another copy of the photo to drawable so I can add it with source and skip the effort

Comment: did you catch any exception?

Comment: isn't there any sub folder in asset?

Comment: no exceptions and no subfolders that's what drive me crazy

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add the `inflatedView` to your `parent` view

use this code:

```
 LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.userlist_list_item, null);
user = (ImageView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.user);
parent.addView(inflatedView);
```

use the Following method:

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName)
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(strName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: sorry but how do I get the id of parent layout ?

Comment: it is the parent layout in your `activity_userlist` ...where you want to add the view

Comment: it added the image over the list but no images in their places ( the images in each list row )

Comment: check the edit...and also `user dashboard.png` remove the space between the name and try.